# non-english Characters are not shown in my excel report

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I have `'http:// || :server || :domain || :app_server_port || '/' ||   :app_dad || '/reports.rep?sqlString=' || myQuery`

The reports shows everything if all the information is in English, but when information in other languages, the data is not shown. I mean the related field is empty. and if all the records contain non-english characters, no records are shown!!!!

Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: You mean non-Latin characters? Don't give the english too much credit

Comment: Do you have appropriate fonts installed in your machine? I guess this has nothing to do with oracle but more with Fonts available to MS Excel.